# TFS Branch refused to go

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs, branch

We are on TFS 2010 and clients being used are VS 2008, VS 2010 and VS 2012.

I use the VS 2010 feature to view TFS hierarchy feature to visualize my TFS branch setup and maintain it.

Question, is that once the work on a branch is complete, I right click and 'Delete' it. After deletion, if I open hierarchy visualization again, sometimes branch box gets removed from the visualization as expected, but sometimes, even though the branch is deleted, it refused to go away from the visualization. Why is it suck, and how can I remove the deleted branch from the visualization?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26658461/excluded-branches-showing-on-tfs-branch-diagram

Answer (score 0):

In source control explorer there is an option to Show / Hide deleted items.  Using standard methods, it's not really possible to actually delete anything in TFS, just flag it as deleted.

If you REALLY want to get rid of the files then you should use [destroy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386005%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Comment: the issue is not in deletion of branches. The issue is that only sometimes, even after deletion the branch box lefts remaining in the visual hierarchy diagram. Most of the times, it gets removed as expected after the branch is deleted.

Comment: Sorry, I may not have explained myself sufficiently; deleting the branch does not remove it from the hierarchy, and so deleted branches will still be visible, because they are still part of the hierarchy.

Comment: Then how do we explain most of the branch boxes go away from visualization after my deletion, while only some remained back?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with a deleted branch hanging around.

Although it's not exactly a brilliant solution, I noticed that you can hover over the offending branch, and click on the [`X`] to remove it (temporarily) from the visualisation.

Which allows you to at least save an image of your nicely refactored hierarchy to impress your friends with, before it comes back next time you run the `View Hierarchy` command.

[image]